# Windows not finding Kdenlive files

Tags: windows, kdenlive

Recently I started creating videos for work, by using OBS Studio to record my screen. Today I downloaded Kdenlive (I run a Windows machine), and followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7N3rXT_5f_I).

Long story short, I am able to edit and render videos inside Kdenlive, I have also saved the project. However, when I try to find anything Kdenlive has produced, Windows cannot locate it.

A specific example:

- I open directory X from Kdenlive, for example so as to open a project or add a video. There, I see the project (.kdenlive) and the video (.mp4). Video is playable (right click => Open with VLC...)
- I navigate to and open the same directory from Windows. There is neither a .kdenlive project, nor a .mp4 video.

Even viewing the directory's Properties from Kdenlive and from Windows shows differences in size and file number. The same happens from e.g. GitBash (`ls` and `du`).

I've also tried to move the .mp4 (accessing it from Kdenlive) to another directory, which is also a Git project. The Git GUI does not find it either.

I could not find anything related in any forum (including this SE). My Kdenlive version is 20.04, and my Windows is set up to show hidden files and directories. Any help is appreciated, I can add images if needed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone happens to have this problem:

- from inside kdenlive, copy the video (even better: make a .zip and copy it)
- also from there, navigate to a folder which is inside a Git project
- paste the video or the archive there
- still from inside kdenlive, open a Git Bash, then commit and push the pasted file
- exit the file explorer and kdenlive
- navigate to the same folder normally and open a Git Bash
- git pull
- your file will be there.